# javascript - sort only certain elements of array according to position in another array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array (let's call it the `orderArray`) with these elements:
16 | 18 | 24 | 31 | 33

I have another array (let's call it `workingArray`) with these elements:
16 | 53 | 24 | 58 | 31 | 18

The `resultArray` could be as follows:
[16, 53, 18, 24, 58, 31], or [16, 18, 53, 24, 58, 31] for example

resultArray should have all the elements from workingArray but with a sorting order that doesn't conflict with orderArray.
Please note

- orderArray and workingArray can have different elements between each other
- elements are unique within the array

I would be really happy if there is already a function/library that does that - I have already tried `_.union` but that doesn't do the job.

Short of some already-made code, what's the easiest algorithm to achieve that?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** the sort order of the elements in resultArray should be changed as less as possible - changes should be strictly done not to conflict with the order in orderArray.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what this would be used for... What problem are you trying to solve? Or is this just a coding exercise?

Comment: This might be obvious, but...can you explain the logic behind the order/contents of the `resultArray`?

Comment: @David I think I already did in my question: "resultArray should have all the elements from workingArray but with a sorting order that doesn't conflict with orderArray."

Comment: Fair enough; I still don't understand (it's kinda late here), but so long as you feel you've explained it to the best of your ability.

Comment: @Ates - live code - the problem would be sooo long to exaplain

Comment: Could `resultArray` be 16 | 18 | 53 | 24 | 58 | 31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main idea:

```
orderArray.filter(inWorkingArray).concat(workingArray.filter(notInOrderArray))
```

(copy `orderArray` ignoring items not in the working array, then tack on items in the `workingArray` that weren't in the order array)

you can use `indexOf` to test membership, or a more efficient implementation (making all the elements keys in an object, which will implicitly convert them to strings, making that optimization not work with non-primitive objects). Below is the simplest example with just `indexOf`, which should generalize even to non-primitive objects like sub-arrays:

```
var inWorkingArray = function(x) {return workingArray.indexOf(x)!=-1};
var notInOrderArray = function(x) {return orderArray.indexOf(x)==-1};
```

result:

```
[16, 18, 24, 31, 53, 58]
```

---

> *That's a good solution, but the order of elements in the result array shouldn't be changed so much - we should try to keep the workingArray with an order as much as the original - sorry I wasn't very clear on that. Please see my edit in the question.* --OP

The question is still not well defined, but this will sort the subset of the workingArray according to the orderArray, leaving elements not in the orderArray in place:

```
var intersection = orderArray.filter(inWorkingArray);
var c=0;
workingArray.map(function(x){
    return notInOrderArray(x) ? x : intersection[c++];
});
```

result:

```
[16, 53, 18, 58, 24, 31]
```

Comment: @dan: a function such as `function(x){return workingArray.indexOf(x)!=-1}`

Comment: That's a good solution, but the order of elements in the result array shouldn't be changed so much - we should try to keep the workingArray with an order as much as the original - sorry I wasn't very clear on that.
Please see my edit in the question.
Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @dan: I'm not sure why you would want that; it's also a fuzzy concept. But if you want to modify the question like that, editing answer.